# momentjs datetime format on frontend with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4, datetimepicker, angular-moment

I'm using currently moment.js in my project. I want to remove **"T"** and **+02:00**. There must be a date and time only. But if I use the .format() method of moment.js I get the default datetime.

I want to format this datetime:

from ' 2022-02-11T04:20:13+02:00 ' to ' 2022-02-11 04:20:13 '

back

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

date_times: any;
constructor() {
this.date_times =  moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}
```

front

```
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Select date & time</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM YYYY H:mm A" (ionChange)="showdate()" [(ngModel)]="date_times"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>

{{date_times }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` will give you the format you want but since you are using `date_times` as the `ngModel` of `<ion-datetime>` component, its value has been changed after you initialized the value in the `constructor()`.

You can format `date_times` when you print it out by using `Pipe` like this:

**my-datetime-format.pipe.ts**:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myDateTimeFormat'
})
export class myDateTimeFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  }
}
```

**In template**:

```js
{{ date_times | myDateTimeFormat }}
```

Comment: Never use function callbacks in an Angular template `formatDatetime(date_times)`, every template change will trigger a call back. Albeit tough with`ngModel` this should not happen but I want to draw your attention to this: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Comment: @Joosep.P Thank you. I updated my answer with using pure `Pipe` instead